# How to integrate Croppie in react js with message hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js

hello friends i am new in react js. i want to integrate [Croppie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) in react js with message hook and also i want to know is this croppie support next.js because i also want to integrate same code in next.js.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crappie is JavaScript library which is working on both reactjs app and next js.

install croppie

```
npm install croppie -save
```

then just use in project

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k5n1l3zym3?file=/src/index.js:0-1993) is the example of using croppie in react js project

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply the line no 22 const croppie = document.getElementById("croppie"); gives errro document not define in react js message hook